# Plugin "react" was conflicted between "package.json » eslint-config-react-app

Tags: reactjs, react-error-boundary

this problem after install react

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNIgd.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The reason is - enter image description here.

Answer (score 5):

I encountered the same error .

The path u created this app is in:

```
\Users\TONMOY\Onedrive\feedback-ui\
```

The path name is case sensitive. You created the app in is case sensitive so you created the app in the folder `...\Onedrive\.....` while the correct path in your device is `...\OneDrive\....`.

This may be an issue of VS Code.

The workaround to this that I found is, in the Visual  Studio terminal I navigated to  the correct folder path with the proper case which in your case should be

```
\Users\TONMOY\OneDrive\feedback-ui\
```

After this running your app from the VS Code terminal should work normally. This worked for me in Visual Studio Code.

Update:
This is just a temporary fix. On restarting VS Code it reverts back to the wrong case.

Instead you could load up VS Code and browse through your system directory and select your project folder manually once. After doing this the path's case does not revert even after restarting.

Comment: I think this is the issue. Only I did it the other way around, I changed the app name folder from "APP1" to "app1" and now no more errors.

Comment: Thanks for posting this response.  I ran into the same issue when I cloned a Git repo in Visual Studio.  I did what you suggested and closed Visual Studio and then reopened it and browsed to the solution path.  It was a mixed case path issue as you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Well I faced the same issue and if run `npm ls eslint-config-react-app` to see the configration and package being used. Or else run `npm update eslint` then finally re-run `npm start`. That should work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I went to node_modules/react-scripts/config .Acutally it's an another folder, and there is no such file as you mentioned above.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Install the node modules package again.
npm i

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me too
went into the file webpack.config.js located in : node_modules > react-scripts > config and i commented all this excerpt located at the end of the file :
Coment all this section

```
  !disableESLintPlugin &&
        new ESLintPlugin({
          // Plugin options
          extensions: ['js', 'mjs', 'jsx', 'ts', 'tsx'],
          formatter: require.resolve('react-dev-utils/eslintFormatter'),
          eslintPath: require.resolve('eslint'),
          failOnError: !(isEnvDevelopment && emitErrorsAsWarnings),
          context: paths.appSrc,
          cache: true,
          cacheLocation: path.resolve(
            paths.appNodeModules,
            '.cache/.eslintcache'
          ),
          // ESLint class options
          cwd: paths.appPath,
          resolvePluginsRelativeTo: __dirname,
          baseConfig: {
            extends: [require.resolve('eslint-config-react-app/base')],
            rules: {
              ...(!hasJsxRuntime && {
                'react/react-in-jsx-scope': 'error',
              }),
            },
          },
        }),
```

Thank u

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when returning to an old react project. I had to update react-scripts package. Information on how to do this can be found here:

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/updating-to-new-releases/

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this when I was trying to set up a test react app with the command `npx create-react-app my-app`. What I did was remove the script below in the package.json

````
"eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },```


I have not delved deeper into the main reason of why the issue but I think this would be helpful somehow.
````

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error, after the following installation to restore normal, hope to help you.

`npm i eslint-config-react-app`

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34479551)

Answer (score -1):

What I did to solve this problem I went into the file **webpack.config.js** located in : **node_modules > react-scripts > config** and i commented all this excerpt located at the end of the file :

```
!disableESLintPlugin &&
    new ESLintPlugin({
      // Plugin options
      extensions: ['js', 'mjs', 'jsx', 'ts', 'tsx'],
      formatter: require.resolve('react-dev-utils/eslintFormatter'),
      eslintPath: require.resolve('eslint'),
      failOnError: !(isEnvDevelopment && emitErrorsAsWarnings),
      context: paths.appSrc,
      cache: true,
      cacheLocation: path.resolve(
        paths.appNodeModules,
        '.cache/.eslintcache'
      ),
      // ESLint class options
      cwd: paths.appPath,
      resolvePluginsRelativeTo: __dirname,
      baseConfig: {
        extends: [require.resolve('eslint-config-react-app/base')],
        rules: {
          ...(!hasJsxRuntime && {
            'react/react-in-jsx-scope': 'error',
          }),
        },
      },
    }),
```